# Time Series Econometrics: VECM with multiple cointegration vectors

Tags: econometrics

Has anyone gone through some papers using Vector Error Correction Models in causality applications with more than one cointegration vectors, say two. I guess there will be more than one ECM terms. How to assess the endogeneity of the  left hand variables if t-stats on different ECM coefficients yield different (conflicting) results. For left hand side variables to be endogenous should we have both ECM coefficients negative and significant?

Javed Iqbal

Comment: Suggested closing this, read it a few times, and wouldn't even know where to begin turning this into something answerable.  OP is long gone.  If anyone understands this question do chime in.